# conjunctions or enumerations inside a sentence make multiple predicates

Tags: grammar, recursion, predicatives

please tell me if in the following example:

`The tree is characterized by long, strong roots.`

Does the enumeration generate two nested (recursion) sentences?

`1. The tree is characterized by long roots.
 2. The tree is characterized by strong roots.`

Other example:

`The tree is characterized by maroon or purple leaves, a dense, oval
    crown and colorful fall foliage.`

In this case, we have as many nested sentences as combinations are posed by enumerations and conjunctions? e.g.

`3. The tree is characterized by maroon leaves.
 4. The tree is characterized by purple leaves.
 5. The tree is characterized by a dense crown.
 6. The tree is characterized by colorful fall foliage.`

I apologize if this is a very simple question; I'm not a linguist. Please tell me how to analyze these cases and what linguistic theory I can see where some examples illustrates the same things.

Comment: I don't understand what you'd like to know. Are you asking whether the grammar rules that enable us to insert adjectives and conjoined phrases are recursive? In this case, the answer is yes: We can apply these rules over and over again and insert as many adjectives or conjuncts as we want, as is visible from your example sentences.

Comment: I suspect the OP is asking about propositional semantics, since 'long, strong roots' isn't a complex predicate in the syntactic sense...

Comment: @OP: If you're asking if the first sentence is semantically equivalent to 1. and 2., I think the answer is certainly 'no'. A tree which is has 50% long, weak roots and 50% short, strong roots would satisfy 1. and 2., but not the original sentence, since no root is both long and strong. (A bit of a contrived example, I know...)

Comment: Please put your question in the form of a question.